# Как можно упростить код по нормам хорошего кода?

Tags: jquery

Написал скрипт, который *проверяет при клике, наличие* **класса** и в зависимости от имеющего **класса**,   *удаляет* и *добавляет* нужный **класс**!

> Скрипт **работает**! Можно ли будет этот скрипт упростить! (по нормам
>   хорошего кода!)

```
$("#m\\.menu\\.button\\.menu , #m\\.menu\\.button\\.menu\\.double , .m\\.dark\\.background").click(function () {
    openOrClose();
});

function openOrClose() {
    $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom").hasClass("m\.menu\.active") ? openMenu() : closeMenu();

    function openMenu() {
        $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom, #m\\.second\\.menu\\.bottom").removeClass();
        $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom").addClass("m\.menu\.disable");
        $("#m\\.second\\.menu\\.bottom").addClass("m\.menu\.active");
    }

    function closeMenu() {
        $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom, #m\\.second\\.menu\\.bottom").removeClass();
        $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom").addClass("m\.menu\.active");
        $("#m\\.second\\.menu\\.bottom").addClass("m\.menu\.disable");
    }
}
```

Для меня будет полезно узнать Ваше мнение и совет!

Comment: Как минимум можно сделать один метод openOrClose(status). В зависимости от статус через if делать нужные операции.

Comment: Для начала половину логики выкинуть в css, и задавайть класс только родителю. Тогда при клике будет две строчки - убрать активный во всех меню, и добавить его в текущий. Ну и непонятны двойные слэши, они тут ненужны. + очень длинная цепочка.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev `"#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom"` использую в html как `id="m.first.menu.bottom"`

Comment: Используйте метод [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) с передачей второго параметра для сокращения и лаконичности вашего кода.

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь, первый раз такое вижу, по всем стандартам `#m.first.menu.bottom` это ` id="m" class="first menu bottom"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openOrClose() { 
        $("#m\\.first\\.menu\\.bottom").toggleClass("m\.menu\.disable");
        $("#m\\.second\\.menu\\.bottom").toggleClass("m\.menu\.active"); 
}
```